# Send a string through serial port

Tags: c++, .net, wpf, opencv

I have an application using OpenCV which basically prints a string using a webcam to track the color of a ball and its movements. If the ball moves to the right, it sends a `string= "right"` | `string = "left"`

I have made a GUI for the interaction (project made on .net and WPF), to show that when the ball moves to the left the user can see it really moves, performing a graphical interaction like the itunes coverflow.

My question is that if is possible to communicate both projects using a virtual serial port and how can I open the port to send this string from the openCV code.

The app on .net is already ready to read the serial port, the baud rate, stop bit etc.

If there is another way to send this string to the project on .net, let me know.

thanks in advance =)

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use a serial link instead of a network connection?

Comment: not really, the thing is i have no idea how to communicate them and because i have tried this using the opencv code on a microcontroller and it works perfectly using serial port, but i want to use the same computer for both apps

Answer (score 1):

The serial port isn't really the right tech for this, if you're after something that allows two separate programs running on the same machine to communicate with each other then the .NET/Windows solution for that is anonymous and/or named pipes. Google "About Pipes" and select the MSDN article (currently listed at the top), that will get you started. Under .NET the C# and C++ code is practically identically and only a few lines long.